# Sign In in asp.net core app with entityframework core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I inherited the IdentityUser class just to add FirstName and LastName property.So, SignInManager class provides two ways to sign in either typing username as string or passing the ApplicationUser class which inherits IdentityUser.

```
public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
{
   public string FirstName {get; set;}
   public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

Now, you can sign in two different ways
One of the ways is:

```
await _signInManager.SignInAsync(new ApplicationUser{UserName = someclass.userName}, someclass.password, true, false);
```

Another way is:

```
await _signInManager.SignInAsync(someclass.userName, someclass.password, true, false);
```

Signing in the user by passing the user info object throws errors saying incorrect password, but signing in the user by passing the string username like in a second way successfully log you in.
Why?
But also, even if you have signed in the user by second way, the VerifyUserTokenAsync is not going to work and you cant reset password or change email address. Help me solve this problem. I want to sign in the user by the first technique.

Comment: It might be better if you write this to official EF Core github page as an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `SignInAsync(new ApplicationUser{...})` you're not loading the rest of user object from the DB. This means the `IdentityUser.PasswordHash` field  is empty.

```cs
public virtual async Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(TUser user, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
{
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
    }

    var attempt = await CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, password, lockoutOnFailure);
    return attempt.Succeeded
        ? await SignInOrTwoFactorAsync(user, isPersistent)
        : attempt;
}
```

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/746b9f82fb5c026ce3ce1aed9b2883078ca9ebe6/src/Identity/Core/src/SignInManager.cs#L330

With `SignInAsync(username, password)`, Identity framework loads the user for you, then checks the credentials, that's why you don't get an error.

```cs
public virtual async Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password,
        bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
{
    var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName); // <---
    if (user == null)
    {
        return SignInResult.Failed;
    }

    return await PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, isPersistent, lockoutOnFailure);
}
```

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/746b9f82fb5c026ce3ce1aed9b2883078ca9ebe6/src/Identity/Core/src/SignInManager.cs#L357

Comment: await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName); doesn't fill up the PasswordHash property.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Does the user actually have a password hash? Does the user identity come from an external identity provider (like Google)?

Comment: Because there's nothing special about `PasswordHash` property. It's loaded from the database just like `Email` or `UserName`. If you're getting `null` as the value, that could only mean that there's no value in the database

Comment: I apologise for my working, I made a test project project to test your code but I forgot to provide a password will registering the user. Your technique worked, thank you.